# How to setup Jdbc path in Oracle Sql Developer?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Under Tools > Preferences > Databases there is a third party JDBC driver path that must be setup. Once the driver path is setup a separate 'MySQL' tab should appear on the New Connections dialog.

Note: This is the same jdbc connector that is available as a JAR download from the MySQL website.

How to setup Jdbc path in Oracle Sql Developer???

Answer (score 2):

Right here. Under `Tools -> Preferences -> Third Party JDBC Drivers`

You click `Add Entry...` button and pick the MySQL JDBC driver.

[image]